# How to host Python Packages in GCP and access them from Compute Engine?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, pypi

Is it possible to have a sort of Python Packages Index hosted in GCP (Google Storage?)?
If yes, how to set it up? And how to access those packages from the compute engines to be able to install them?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to cache https://pypi.org/? Or do you want a library of your own Python packages that you created? https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-use-remote-python-modules AND https://gemfury.com/help/pypi-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to serve Python Packages in Cloud Storage.

As per the [Python docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/#id3):

> simply create the proper directory structure and use any web server that can serve static files and generate an autoindex.

Google Cloud Storage does not provide the autoindex functionality.

I also don't think Google Cloud Source Repositories would work because it [needs authentication](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control#granting_member_access).

What you could do is set a Google App Engine service to serve the packages. The packages could be stored in Cloud Storage but they would be served with GAE. I found [this project (GAEPyPI)](https://github.com/ml2grow/GAEPyPI) that might be useful